# Fill gridview(refresh) while long running process

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, multithreading, .net-4.0

I have a method which runs for different values which goes to database, retrieve values and fill a `gridview` row by row.

Each call takes some time and screen freeze until process finish. I like to display values in `gridview` while the method running and without freezing the screen.

I tried something like below which still freezes the screen and I can’t see values on grid until process finish.

I don’t want to use `Application.Doevents` which display the data in grid if I used it with in the loop.

Any help is appreciate

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim t = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf MyWork)
        t.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub MyWork()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf DoWork))
        End If
End Sub

Private Function DoWork() As Boolean

    For i As Integer = 1 To 1000000
        FillGrid(i)
    Next    
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class which has a [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event that allows you to provide intermediate updates to the user interface during your long operation. In the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) function, you can call [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) several times and pass any object to the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event to update the UI.

Here is a simple example to show the concept. First add a `BackgroundWorker` to the form in designer view from the `ToolBox`. The instance will show up at the bottom of the designer window. Select the `BackgroundWorker` and set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property equal to `True`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim list1 As New List(Of String)
    list1.Add("A")
    list1.Add("B")
    list1.Add("C")
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress("50", list1)
    Dim list2 As New List(Of String)
    list2.Add("1")
    list2.Add("2")
    list2.Add("3")
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress("100", list2)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Dim myList As List(Of String)
    myList = e.UserState
    For Each str As String In myList
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(str)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    MessageBox.Show("Operation Complete")
End Sub
```

Here is an explanation of what is going on. In the `DoWork` routine, you will be performing your long operation on a `separate thread` than the UI. When you call the `ReportProgress` function, you can pass it two parameters: a percentage and an object... the second parameter is more important in this case. In the `ProgressChanged` routine, you will take the same object from `e.UserState` and do what you want with it. This happens on the `UI thread` so you can update your controls from here. The `RunWorkerCompleted` routine is called when the operation is finished and also runs on the `UI thread`. The important thing to take away from this is that a thread-safe handoff is performed between the `BackgroundWorker` and the `UI` whenever you call the `ReportProgress` function.

Comment: I tried that which brings the `cross thread` error. Do you have an idea how i can transfrom above situation to background worker?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Could you show us what you do to get this error? You are probably calling the UI thread in the wrong method (thread).

Comment: @Mash: Thanks mash it worked fine. It did refresh the grid while process running. But only problem I have is still the form get freezed until process finish. You have any idea why?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: It could be that you have so many rows that even the act of adding rows to your `DataGridView` is making the form unresponsive. If this is the case, you might want to look into filling your own table in memory first, then set the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` to your table in memory. Take a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141519/vb-how-to-bind-a-datatable-to-a-datagridview) to see if this is something you might be interested in doing.