# Datagridview: How to pull only latest record for each Member ID from Access database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to create a library management system and using a DataGridView to see a list of people defaulted on payment (last payment date is more than 2 months old).

To do this, I plan to

1. Query the payment table for each Member ID and pick their last record,

   2. Then do a check on payment date on this record and display it if it is more than two months old.

Can someone please help me with the code in VB. I am not able to make much progress on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the payment table with a [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) Clause

eg.(Assume you're on MSSQL)

`SELECT MemberID,WhatEverYouNeed 
FROM PaymentTable 
WHERE PaymentDate<DATEADD(MONTH,-2,GETDATE())`

It will return you a set of result, if any.
Fill it with a [SqlDataAdapter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter). Then, [bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141519/vb-how-to-bind-a-datatable-to-a-datagridview) the datatable to your DGV