# Binding a datagridview to a datasource using a combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, binding, datasource

I read these before asking:

[VB: How to bind a DataTable to a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141519/vb-how-to-bind-a-datatable-to-a-datagridview)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.100).aspx

I have a very simple problem. The vb.net winforms project contains several datatables, a combobox and a datagridview.

I can select the datatable to display thus:

`datagridview1.datasource = dt1 'or dt2 or dt3`

and this works fine.

What I want to do is select the datatable to display from the combobox selection where I have previously defined a combobox collection of items thus:

```
combobox1.item.add("dt1")
combobox1.item.add("dt2")
combobox1.item.add("dt3")
```

I placed this line

`datagridview.datasource = combobox1.SelectedItem`

in the `ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event.

This just blanks my datagridview. My initial thought was that this fails because I am passing a string to something that expects an object so I have tried `datagridview.datasource = CObj(combobox1.SelectedItem)` but with no better result.

What simple thing am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add your DataTable objects references directly to the `ComboBox.Items` collection.

```
combobox1.DisplayMember = "TableName"
combobox1.DataSource = {dt1, dt2, dt3}
' Or... (DisplayMember value applies anyway)
'combobox1.Items.AddRange({dt1, dt2, dt3})
```

In the ComboBox [SelectionChangeCommitted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted) event handler, set the `DataGridView.DataSource`:

```
Private Sub combobox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combobox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DirectCast(combobox1.SelectedItem, DataTable)
End Sub
```

If you want to use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead, check whether `SelectedIndex < 0` and just `Return` if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ComboBox` is just a list of strings, so when you do `datagridview.datasource = combobox1.SelectedItem` you're not actually setting the datasource to a datatable.

What I would do this this in your `ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```vb
Select Case combobox1.SelectedItem
    Case "dt1"
        datagridview1.datasource = dt1
    Case "dt2"
        datagridview1.datasource = dt2
    Case "dt3"
        datagridview1.datasource = dt3
End Select
```

Comment: A nice way for experienced guys like us ;) , however may be slightly lengthy and stranger for beginners.

Comment: Thanks. I was just typing out an answer to my own question involving an if combobox.SelectedIndex = 0 then..... list of statements when your answer popped up. I appreciate your time.

Comment: If you have solved your issue, you should accept one of the answers or write your own answer if you used a different method and accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually code in c# but this roundabout method would work:

```
    If combobox1.SelectedItem = "dt1" Then
        datagridview1.DataSource = dt1
    ElseIf combobox1.SelectedItem = "dt2" Then
        datagridview1.DataSource = dt2
    ElseIf combobox1.SelectedItem = "dt3" Then
        datagridview1.DataSource = dt3
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks. I was just typing out an answer to my own question involving an if combobox.SelectedIndex = 0 then..... list of statements when your answer popped up. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @DaveLowe:     Oh! Really didn't see your name beneath that answer. I thought you were starting with vb.net. xD

Comment: @DaveLowe:     Also index would be harder if you don't know the indexes of the combobox items and their order. There, SelectedItem works better.